# Why not to store multiple values in one columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, blob

I Am using SQL Server.

I have a table that have a lot of columns that part of them are not been used in queries.

My question is why not to save them into one column as blob or as XML column?

Is there disadvantage or some kind of reason why not to do it?

Comment: What if you (or anyone) have to query on them in the future ?

Comment: Let say that I am sure that no one will query them.

Comment: If no one will EVER query them, it might be simpler for you to just delete them. I don't know enough about your requirements though to say with any certainty.

Comment: Most of the information is used by the application server that communicate to the database. I need to store the information and getting the information but I don't need to filter the result by most of the columns

Comment: Same story. If you keep retrieving part of this information, it will be expensive to continually read a blob/parse XML just to get the tiny little integer hidden at the end of it. But if you ALWAYS need to retrieve the whole pack of information, then why not.

Answer (score 2):

I always tell my customers that everything in the world of data storage is a tradeoff. An RDBMS provides things like durability, isolation, consistency and atomicity (commonly referred to as ACID). But that comes at a price of fairly complex and rigid schema setup and maintenance requirements and , depending on your data, even performance.

What you need to ask yourself (or your stakeholders) is what that data is needed for, in which circumstances it needs to be accessed, how long you can wait for the data in such an event. Then you need to write down the advantages and disadvantages of all solutions similar to this:

*Separate Columns*

1. relational storage optimized for integrity,performance,storage
2. high maintenance overhead for DBA
3. modifications to schema expensive
4. fully ACID compliant

*String Blob*

1. rigid storage, expensive to automatically read/search/modify
2. simple table schema
3. no structure on the data enforced
4. very slow to find data
5. severely restricted ACID properties

*XML*

1. flexible storage that can enforce a schema
2. slow to find data, could be improved with index
3. values can be directly queried
4. restricted ACID properties
5. high storage overhead

Now this is by far not a complete list. Some of the points mentioned might also be an advantage for one project but a disadvantage for another. After you have weight all the benefits and disadvantages it should be easier to figure out wich way is the right one to go in you situation.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, it depends :)

For example:

- I'm currently storing a complete server configuration in a single SQL Table XML Field that I'm able to retrieve querying the row keys (1 or at most 2 fields). 
  It's useful, better than n different fields for parameters, but a little bit complicated due to xquery complexity. I can do it without violations of best practices because it's a really huge configuration. I will never do it for a "Name Surname Address" table!
- Less fields = Less parameters in case of Code behind Query generator (or SP).
- Be careful with XML, you need to validate it and check for blank, invalid characters and so on.
- SQL Table with many fields is good for storage & searching. XML is good for transmitting & formatting (to/from application).

Remember:

> “XML is not a database. It was never meant to be a database. It is never going to be a database. Relational databases are proven technology with more than 20 years of implementation experience. They are solid, stable, useful products. They are not going away. XML is a very useful technology for moving data between different databases or between databases and other programs. However, it is not itself a database. Don't use it like one.“

Comment: Database by basic are data storage. Search information by query is major tool but not for all scenario. In this case i need only to store the information and get rows only by ID in a diff column so i don't need to access the xml/blob column from the database, just buffering the information by request.

Answer (score 1):

If the only use case for this data is *application server retrieves the whole thing* then clearly it is not "multiple values" but one value.  Oh sure, the client app needs to parse the string into several pieces but the database doesn't care.

Hence it would be quite legitimate to store this as a single column.

However, you say in a comment:

> "Most of the information is used by the application server that communicate to the database. I need to store the information and getting the information but I don't need to filter the result by most of the columns"

"Most of" is not the same as "all of".  If the database has to exercise some intelligence about the column's contents, well then you have a problem and you should really store it as separate columns - key/value pairs if you must - or as XML.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to read the Wikipedia article on [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).
Depending on the case, you might create redundancy, which will lead to inconsistency or anomalies.

For example think of a list of people with their cd/mp3 collection. Let's assume you stored the CD titles as a list in one column. After filling up the list with 100 entries, you noticed a typo and fix the title for one person. Due to the lack of time you did not fix the others (inconsistency).

After a while you will notice that your database demands for quite a lot of memory(just for example). 
Looking into your entries, you will find several people having same CDs. It becomes clear that you store same cd tilte several times (Redundancy).